# Python properties: Two instances of variable?

Tags: python, django

Really confused about what's going on here. I have a class defined as follows:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    primary_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)

    @property
    def primary_email(self): return self.user.email
    @primary_email.setter
    def primary_email(self, val): self.user.email = val
```

NB: `user` has an attribute `email`.

Now from the commandline, I'm trying this:

```
>>> u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> u.email = 'xxx'
>>> u.profile.primary_email
u'yyy'
```

It spits out a different value? Specifically, the *old* value of `u.email`. What's going on? How is this possible? I basically just want to create an alias for `email`.

---

Some more info:

```
>>> id(u) == id(u.profile.user)
False
>>> u
<User: mark>
>>> u.profile.user
<User: mark>
```

They seem to be different copies of `user`, but they... what? Both start with the same values?

Doing this seems to commit the changes:

```
>>> u.profile.primary_email = 'yyy'
>>> u.profile.user.save()
```

But `u.save()` won't do the trick because `u != u.profile.user` for whatever reason. I guess that answers my question, but it's still kind of lame.

It is *possible* for those two to refer to the same object in Python, right? It was just a funny design decision in Django that's causing this?

Comment: Where's the code that creates User.profile? `id(u) == id(u.profile.user)`?

Comment: @outis: It's there: `user = models.OneToOneField(User)`. Django is magical like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python properties per se [do not work](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3148) in django models because django's models do some magic to set instance attributes. Maybe this is having an effect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Django user, but I'd guess it's because you didn't update the model after changing `u.email`. Try calling `u.save()` (or whatever the method happens to be called) before accessing the user's email through the profile.

You can use Django's [signaling](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) feature to build a workaround. Basically, update `Profile.user` when `User` sends [`post_save`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save):

```
# models.py
...
def update_user(**kwargs):
    kwargs['instance'].profile.user = kwargs['instance']

models.signals.post_save.connect(update_user, sender=User)
```

You still need to call `User.save` for this to work, and clobbering `Profile.user` may have other side effects. There might be a more Django-y way; someone with more Django experience than I may yet post it. For example, it may be possible to hook the code that gets called the first time you access `User.profile` and set `Profile.user` to the parent user, instead of creating a new `User`.

Alternatively, whenever you get a user via `Users.objects.get` and reference `Users.profile`, replace the user object with the user property from `User.profile`.

Comment: You are correct in guessing it's `u.save()`, but that doesn't work. And regardless, printing `u.email` without saving will print "xxx". I thought with the properties, it would refer to that exact same instance variable?

Comment: `u.profile.user` most likely refers to a wrapper around the DB object;  `id(u) == id(u.profile.user)` will tell you a little more, as will examining the properties of the various objects.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know about this `id` function. You're right, they're different.

Comment: Nice edit. That could work... this was really just a convenience property anyway. It's not a huge deal. Wanted it to be consistent, so that both the phone and email properties appear on the profile, instead of one here, and one there.